# How to avoid that Doxygen recognizes global instances in C++ code as function declarations?

Tags: c++, doxygen

In my `main.cpp`, Doxygen recognizes the instantiation of the `uart` object as a function declaration. This only happens for objects that have a constructor with parameters (e.g. `timer_a` is perfectly recognized).

Setting the `\var` property in the comment doesn't work.

Here is a code snippet:

```
#include "uart.h"

/**
 * \brief The global object for accessing UART.
 */
Uart uart(FIFO_SIZE_UART, &timer_a);

/**
 * \brief The global timer object.
 */
Timer_A timer_a;
```

Comment: I forgot: timer_a is of course instantiated before the uart object and uart.h is already commented with the \file property.

Comment: try using the equals initialization form  - Uart uart = Uart(FIFO_SIZE_UART, &timer_a);  it does exactly the same thing but looks different

Comment: If you are using C++11, you could use list-initializtion, `Uart uart{FIFO_SIZE_UART, &timer_a};`.

Comment: @Holt as long as `Uart` does not have overload for *list-initialization*.

Comment: @Zereges True for the general case, but since the type of the two arguments are different and not convertible (I assume), this should not be a problem here.